# Number rows per group with RevoScaleR

Tags: r, revolution-r

I'm converting a local R script to make use of the `RevoScaleR` functions in the Revolution-R (aka Microsoft R Client/Server) package. This to be able to scale better with large amounts of data.

The goal is to create a new column that numbers the rows per group. Using `data.table` this would be achieved using the following code:

```
library(data.table)
eventlog[,ActivityNumber := seq(from=1, to=.N, by=1), by=Case.ID]
```

For illustration purposes, the output is something like this:

```
    Case.ID    ActivityNumber
1       A              1
2       A              2
3       B              1
4       C              1
5       C              2
6       C              3
```

After some research to do this using the `rx`-functions I found the package `dplyrXdf`, which is basically a wrapper to use `dplyr`functions on `Xdf`stored data, while still benefitting from the optimized functions of `RevoScaleR` (see http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/10/using-the-dplyrxdf-package.html)

In my case, this would lead to the following:

```
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivityNumber = seq_len(n()))
```

However, this leads to the following error:

```
ERROR: Attempting to add a variable without a name to an analysis.
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 3756. ThreadID: 1248 Rethrowing.
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5249. ThreadID: 1248 Rethrowing.
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  Error in executing R code: ERROR: Attempting to add a variable without a name to an analysis.
```

Any ideas how to solve this error? Or other (better?) approaches to get the requested result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt-parker for pointing me to this question.

Note that `n()` is not a regular R function, although it looks like one. It needs to be implemented specially for each data source, and maybe also separately for each of `mutate`, `summarise` and `filter`.

Right now, the only usage of `n` that is supported for xdf files is within `summarise`, to count the number of rows. Implementing it for the other verbs is actually nontrivial.

In particular, there is a problem with Matt's use of `seq_along` to implement `n`'s functionality. Remember that xdf files are block-structured: each chunk of rows is read in and processed independently of other chunks. This means that the sequence generated is *for that chunk of rows only*, and *not* for all the rows in a group. If a group spans more than one chunk, the sequence numbers will restart in the middle.

The way to get correct sequence numbers is to keep a running count of how many rows you've read in for that group, and update it each time a chunk is processed. You can do this with a `transformFunc`, which you pass to `transmute` via the `.rxArgs` argument:

```
ev <- eventlog %>% group_by(Case.ID) %>% transmute(.rxArgs = list(
    transformFunc = function(varList) {
        n <- .n + seq_along(varList[[1]])
        if(!.rxIsTestChunk)  # need this b/c rxDataStep does a test run on the 1st 10 rows
            .n <<- n[length(n)]
        list(n=n)
    },
    transformObjects = list(.n = 0))
```

This should work with the `local`, `localpar` and `foreach` compute contexts. It may not work (or at least won't give a reproducible result) with any context where you can't guarantee that rxDataStep will process the rows in a deterministic order -- so Mapreduce, Spark, Teradata or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this works, but try using `seq_along(Case.ID)` instead of `seq_len(n())`:

```
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivityNumber = seq_along(Case.ID))
```

It seems to be some problem with `n()`. Here's my exploratory code, in case anyone else wants to experiment:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyrXdf)

# Set up some test data
eventlog_df <- data.frame(Case.ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"))

# Add a variable for artificially splitting the XDF into small chunks
eventlog_df$Chunk.ID <- factor((seq_len(nrow(eventlog_df)) + 2) %/% 3)

# Check the results
eventlog_df


# Now read it into an XDF file. I'm going to read just three rows in at a time
# so that the XDF file has several chunks, so we can be confident this works
# across chunks

eventlog <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")

for(i in 1:3) {
    rxImport(inData = eventlog_df[eventlog_df$Chunk.ID %in% i, ],
             outFile = eventlog,
             colInfo = list(Case.ID = list(type = "factor", 
                                           levels = c("A", "B", "C"))),
             append = file.exists(eventlog))
}

# Convert to a proper data source
eventlog <- RxXdfData(eventlog)

rxGetInfo(eventlog, getVarInfo = TRUE, numRows = 10)


# Now to dplyr. First, let's make sure it can count up the records
# in each group without any trouble.
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  summarise(ActivityNumber = n())

# It can:
rxDataStep(result)


# Now if we switch to mutate, does n() still work?
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivityNumber = n())

# No - and it seems to be complaining about missing variables. So what if
# we try to refer to a variable we *know* exists?
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivityNumber = seq_along(Case.ID))

# It works
rxDataStep(result)
```

Comment: It works indeed. Strange thing is that it sometimes failes with larger datasets (giving the exact same error as n()). I do not know if dplyrXdf is to blame, or something else...

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` and `dplyrXdf` have a `tally` method that counts items per group:

```
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  tally()
```

If you want to do more than just tabulate the records per group, you can use summarize (since you didn't show your data, I'm using a hypothetical column called delay, which I'm assuming is numeric for illustrative purposes):

```
result <- eventlog %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  summarize(counts = n(),
            ave_delay = mean(delay))
```

You could do the above with regular `RevoScaleR` functions,

```
rxCrossTabs(~ Case.ID, data = eventlog)
```

and for the second example:

```
rxCube(delay ~ Case.ID, data = eventlog)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but this does not answer my question. I do not want to get the total number of records per group, I want to number the records for each group.


See the desired output from the data.table. The group_by is only used to assess where the numbering should start again from 0.